# Does this seems like a reasonable definition of a uniform distribution?

Tags: distributions, terminology

Does this seem like a reasonable definition of a uniform distribution?

Let
\begin{align}
&S \text{ be a sample space}; \tag{1} \\
&X:S\rightarrow \mathbb{R} \; \text{ be a random variable on } S. \tag{2} \\
\end{align}
Then
\begin{align}
& X(S) \text{ is distributed uniformly } \\
\Leftrightarrow &\text{ every realisation of } X \text{ has pre-image of equal size}, \tag{3.1}\\
\Leftrightarrow &\forall \; x_1,x_2 \in X(S): \; |X^{-1}(\{x_1\})|=|X^{-1}(\{x_2\})|. \tag{3.2}
\end{align}

Comment: I think this is correct if $X$ can only take a finite number of values. 
For a continuous random variable, the preimage of any value is of measure equal to zero, even if the random variable is not uniform.

Comment: This definition even doesn't have a probability measure $P$ in it so it is invalid.

Comment: Cross-posted at https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3680737/321264.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let me answer the implicit question: **what is a uniform distribution?**

Because $X$ is a random variable, $S$ really is the underlying set in a probability space $(S,\mathfrak F, \mathbb P).$

> We say $X$ *has a continuous uniform distribution* when there exists a subset $A\subset \mathbb R$ such that, for every interval $(a,b]\subset \mathbb{R},$ $$\mathbb{P}(X\in (a,b]) \ \propto\  \lambda((a,b]\cap A)$$ where $\lambda$ is Lebesgue measure.
>
> $X$ *has a discrete uniform distribution* when there exists $A\subset \mathbb{R}$ such that for every interval $(a,b],$ $$\mathbb{P}(X\in (a,b])\ \propto\ |(a,b] \cap A|$$ where $|\cdot |$ is the cardinality of a set.

The implicit normalizing constants (denominators) in these equations are $\lambda(A)$ in the first case and $|A|$ in the second, both of which (therefore) must be finite and nonzero.  In particular,

- in the continuous case, $X$ has a *probability density function* equal to $$f_X(x) = \frac{1}{\lambda(A)} \mathcal{I}_A(x)$$ (where $\mathcal{I}_A$ is the indicator function of $A$);
- in the discrete case we may write $|A|=n$ (a nonzero natural number) and see that for any number $x\in \mathbb R,$ $\Pr(X=x) = 1/n$ when $x\in A$ and otherwise $\Pr(X=x)=0.$ This defines the *probability mass function* of $X.$

Comment: Are there some fundamental properties of $\lambda$ and $|\cdot|$ as measures that make them suitable for uniformity, like translation invariance plus $\sigma$-finiteness, in a way that doesn't require a discrete/continuous distinction?

Comment: @jld That's an interesting question.  It exposes the role of a group operation on the codomain of $X.$

Comment: Ah interesting, thank you