# Is there something like a uniform distribution bounded on two intervals (or a uniform distribution with a gap in between)?

Tags: distributions, uniform-distribution

Let's say that I want to have a distribution from which there is an equal probability to draw a number between -0.9 and -0.3 and also a number between 0.2 and 0.8. Is there a distribution which allows you to do this? If yes, how is it called and how does the notation look? If not, is there a reason why this is not possible?

Comment: It's called a uniform distribution.  Searching our site for [uniform distribution](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=%22uniform%20distribution%22&searchOn=3) turns up many interesting examples.  In my search I found a general definition of uniform distributions at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/467197.  Helpful terminology is "support," which refers to the smallest closed set with 100% probability.  The support of your distribution is disconnected -- but the distribution remains uniform on its support.  There are myriad ways to specify such distributions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is, and it is still called uniform distribution.  In general, if a  non-negligible Borel set $A \subset \mathbb{R}$ is has positive finite Lebesgue measure, and let $0 < \lambda(A) < \infty$ be its Lebesgue measure, then the density
\begin{align}
f(x) = \frac{1}{\lambda(A)}I_{A}(x)
\end{align}
defines a probability measure on $\mathbb{R}$.  In your case, simply take $A = (-0.9, -0.3)\cup (0.2, 0.8)$.

Comment: Great, and just a follow up question. Let's say that we want to say that some random variable is distributed according to this distribution; usually if there is just one interval, we would write it like $X \sim \mathcal{U}_{[-0.9, -0.3]}$. But with two intervals, how would it look like?

Comment: $X \sim \mathcal{U}_{[-0.9, -0.3] \cup [0.2,0.8]}$

Comment: You can write $X \sim \mathcal{U}([-0.9, -0.3] \cup [0.2, 0.8])$.  Or more succinctly, $X \sim f$.